# @ControllerAdvice on the method level

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I have two ControllerAdvices in my spring mvc project.

```
//return the json message
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class) 
public class AdviceRestController

//redirect to the error
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class) 
public class AdviceController
```

now, I have some @ResponseBody  annotated method in the @Controller  annotated class. Is there any  annotation for the method level, then I can write the method in my AdviceController for  @ResponseBody  annotated method only.

i.e.

```
//reoponsebody method only
@ReoponsebodyMethod
@ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public String handleIllegalStateException(Exception ex) {
    //return son
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to do. You can implement a `ControllerAdvice` annotated class that implements `ResponseBodyAdvice<T>`.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyResponseBodyCustomizer implements ResponseBodyAdvice<ResponseBodyObject> {
  @Override
  boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  ResponseBodyObject beforeBodyWrite(Caravan body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Strelok, It's been a long time. I use a workaround solution before. I want to catch the exception in the  Reoponsebody annotated method only.